# Installing Windows on a MacBook Air

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp

I'm very new to Macs. My supervisor wants me to install Windows on his MacBook Air. I'm pretty confused about what to do. This MacBook Air runs 10.7.2 and there is an update for 10.7.5 which is around 2.7GB. Now what my questions are;

- Can I install Windows without updating the OS?
- If so, do I have to download any supporting drivers or can I just go with Boot Camp assistant?
- Do I need – or is there any way – to backup the current OS X installation?

Comment: Have you searched [AskDifferent](http://www.askdifferent.com) for an answer? It is a companion site to this one which focuses on Apple products and help.

Comment: I didn't note that site. thank you for hooking up. I'll do a search and I'll post it there. thank you once again.

Comment: @Bert Please do not point users to other sites without explaining that we do not allow cross-posting. Azker, please don't post the question again on [Apple.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Use Bootcamp Assistant
3. If you want to back up use Carbon Copy Cloner or Time Machine

Answer (score 0):

Is he looking to have windows running natively on his mac? If yes, use Bootcamp Assistant like Tobi mentioned.

However, all he might be looking for is to run windows on a virtual machine. For most users, especially non-power users like your supervisor appears to be, this a great, simple solution. Parallels or VMWare Fusion are both great products. I'm a fan of VMWare myself.

http://www.parallels.com/ca/

http://www.vmware.com/ca/en/products/fusion/

Comment: I run several Windows VM with [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org/) and not a problem so far. It is free and it is from Oracle. Good enough for me.

Comment: Hi!! I'm actually looking to run windows natively. What my question was; If I'm using bootcamp assistant do I have to download windows drivers? or will the boot camp do it by itself while going through the process.